# Makefile warning: linker input file unused because linking not done

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, linker

I'm trying to write my own makefile for a C++ program.
I'm editing an old makefile for a C program one of my teacher gave m, but I really don't understand why it keeps telling me that `linking is not done`.

I have 4 classes with their corresponding headers plus the `main` file.

This is my makefile:

```
OBJS = main.o Class1.o Class2.o Class3.o Class4.o
HEADERS = Class1.hpp Class2.hpp Class3.hpp Class4.hpp
EXE = main
all: $(EXE)

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall
LFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -g

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rules
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

RM = rm -rf

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp
.cpp.o :
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS)

$(OBJS) : $(HEADERS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)
    $(RM) $(EXE)

again:                                                               
    make clean
    make
```

And these are the error messages I get when I try to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall -o main main.o Class1.o Class2.o Class3.o Class4.o
g++: warning: main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: Class1.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: Class2.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: Class3.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: Class4.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

I understand that this might be because I'm not linking all the `.o` files together at the end, but isn't it what this line

```
$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS)
```

is supposed to do? Since the `-c` option is not present.

What am I missing?

Thank you everybody for the help.

Comment: You have `-c` specified on your link line -- that explicitly prevents linking.  Your `$(EXE): $(OBJS)` rule should probably use `$(LFLAGS)` rather than `$(CXXFLAGS)`.

Comment: Actually, best practice is to include the `*FLAGS` variables on the link line because they often contain flags that the linker is interested in; however, you should _NOT_ put `-c` into the `*FLAGS` variables, for exactly this reason.  The `-c` option should be included in the recipe directly, not through variables.  Here, it _is_ included in the recipe but then it's also included in the `CXXFLAGS` variable.  It just needs to be removed from `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: You're both right. I don't know why but I didn't see that. I feel so dumb... Thank you!

Comment: @MadScientist, I'd say that **best** practice is to use Make's predefined variables as much as possible - so write `$(LINK.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^` as the command for `$(EXE)` (and omit the `.cpp.o` rule).